# Doctrine 2: Getting records based on at least one record with a specific attribute?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony project in an SQL query I would like to retrieve all customers with at least one active order. Here comes my query in my Orders Repository:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'o' )
            ->select( [
                'c.firstname',
                'c.lastname'
              ] )
            ->join( '\MyBundle\Entity\Contacts',
                    'c',
                    'WITH',
                    'c.crmid = o.idCustomer' );
```

There is a field in my Orders table called "isActive" which can have the value 0 or 1. How do I achieve that I only get those customers who have at least one order with `isActive = 1`, considering also orders which are not active anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You must do a Subquery, like this:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'o' )
        ->select(
        'c.firstname',
        'c.lastname'
        )
        ->addSelect('(
            SELECT COUNT(or.id)
            FROM  MyBundle\Entity\Orders AS or
            WHERE  or.contact = c.id
            AND or.isActive = 1
         ) as orders_num
        ')
        ->join( '\MyBundle\Entity\Contacts',
            'c',
            'WITH',
            'c.crmid = o.idCustomer' )
        ->having('orderes_num > 0')
```